# Customized Underline with gradient API in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to recreate this Underline Effect from this Codepen with React and Typescript

**The** **Codepen:** https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/jOzwXww

I think my issue in the code down below is the interface, I started to declare my types but still it does not recognize them. It says they are any. But max is declared as number but shows up as any still. I am unsure why. The functions are described as comments.

**tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

interface Props {
   max: number;
}

const styles = {
   body: {
       width: "80%",
       margin: "10vw auto",
     },

     heading: {
       fontFamily: "Playfair Display, serif",
       fontSize: "10vw",
     },
     
     "subheading": {
       fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
       fontSize: "1em",
       lineHeight: "1.5",
     },
     
     "@media screen and (min-width: 40em)": {
       body: {
         width: "50%",
       },
       heading:{
         fontSize: "6vw",
       },
     
       subheading: {
         fontSize: "1.75vw",
       }
     },
     
     "underline--magical": {
       backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%)",
       backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
       backgroundSize: "100% 0.2em",
       backgroundPosition: "0 88%",
       transition: "backgroundSize 0.25s ease-in",
       "&:hover": {
         backgroundSize: "100% 88%",
       },
     },
};

function Effect(props: Props) {

   // VARIABLES
const magicalUnderlines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.underline--magical'));

const gradientAPI = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wking-io/3e116c0e5675c8bcad8b5a6dc6ca5344/raw/4e783ce3ad0bcd98811c6531e40256b8feeb8fc8/gradient.json';

// HELPER FUNCTIONS

// 1. Get random number in range. Used to get random index from array.
const randNumInRange = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1));

// 2. Merge two separate array values at the same index to 
// be the same value in new array.
const mergeArrays = (arrOne, arrTwo) => arrOne
 .map((item, i) => `${item} ${arrTwo[i]}`)
 .join(', ');

// 3. Curried function to add a background to array of elms
const addBackground = (elms) => (color) => {
 elms.forEach(el => {
   el.style.backgroundImage = color;
 });
}
// 4. Function to get data from API
const getData = async(url): Promise<XMLHttpRequest> => {
 const response = await fetch(url);
 const data = await response.json();
 return data.data;
}

// 5. Partial Application of addBackground to always apply 
// background to the magicalUnderlines constant
const addBackgroundToUnderlines = addBackground(magicalUnderlines);

// GRADIENT FUNCTIONS

// 1. Build CSS formatted linear-gradient from API data
const buildGradient = (obj) => `linear-gradient(${obj.direction}, ${mergeArrays(obj.colors, obj.positions)})`;

// 2. Get single gradient from data pulled in array and
// apply single gradient to a callback function
const applyGradient = async(url, callback): Promise<XMLHttpRequest> => {
 const data = await getData(url);
 const gradient = buildGradient(data[randNumInRange(data.length)]);
 callback(gradient);
}

// RESULT
applyGradient(gradientAPI, addBackgroundToUnderlines);
   return (
       <Box>
           <Typography sx={styles.heading}>
               Look At This <span style={styles['underline--magical']}>Pretty</span> Underline
           </Typography>
           <Typography sx={styles.subheading}>
               Wow this one is super incredibly cool, and this{' '}
               <span style={styles['underline--magical']}>one is on Multiple Lines!</span> I wish I had found this like thirty
               projects ago when I was representing the lollipop guild.
           </Typography>
       </Box>
   );
}
export { Effect };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To generate a random gradient you have two arrays **colors** and **position**, but for `linear-gradient` we need a string of tuples. I created a helper function **generateGradientRangeArray** to get this string.
2. Since we using React, we can create a hook (**useGradient**) to fetch data from outside and transform it right here.
3. Using the **@emotion** and Material UI components, we add additional propperties to **Box** and **Typography**
4. And finally we create the **Underline** component, check the gradient property, and pass props to the style.

##### App.tsx

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import { Underline } from "./Underline";
import useGradient from "./useGradient";

const Heading = styled(Typography)`
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    font-size: 6vw;
  }
`;
const Subheading = styled(Typography)`
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    font-size: 1.75vw;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  const gradient = useGradient();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box>
        <Heading>
          Look At This <Underline gradient={gradient}>Pretty</Underline>{" "}
          Underline
        </Heading>
        <Subheading>
          Wow this one is super incredibly cool, and this{" "}
          <Underline gradient={gradient}>one is on Multiple Lines!</Underline> I
          wish I had found this like thirty projects ago when I was representing
          the lollipop guild.
        </Subheading>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

##### useGradient.ts

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { generateGradientRangeArray, randNumInRange } from "./Helpers";
import { GradientType, IResult } from "./types";

const GRADIENT_API =
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wking-io/3e116c0e5675c8bcad8b5a6dc6ca5344/raw/4e783ce3ad0bcd98811c6531e40256b8feeb8fc8/gradient.json";

const useGradient = () => {
  const [gradients, setGradients] = useState<GradientType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async (url: string): Promise<void> => {
      // get the data from the api
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const result = (await response.json()) as IResult;
      // Get single gradient from data pulled in array
      const gradient = result.data[randNumInRange(result.data.length)];
      const transform = generateGradientRangeArray(gradient);
      // set state with the result
      setGradients(transform);
    };
    // Catching errors
    getData(GRADIENT_API).catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return gradients;
};

export default useGradient;
```

##### Underline.tsx

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Props, GradientType } from "./types";

const UnderlineStyle = styled.span<{ gradient: GradientType }>`
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    ${(props) => props.gradient.direction},
    ${(props) => props.gradient.range}
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 0.2em;
  background-position: 0 88%;
  transition: background-size 0.25s ease-in;
  &:hover {
    background-size: 100% 88%;
  }
`;

export const Underline = ({ children, gradient }: Props) => {
  if (!gradient) return null;
  return <UnderlineStyle gradient={gradient}>{children}</UnderlineStyle>;
};
```

##### Helpers.ts

```js
import { IGradient, GradientType } from "./types";
/// HELPER FUNCTIONS

// Get random number in range. Used to get random index from array.
export const randNumInRange = (max: number) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1));

// Create range of colors for gradient
export const generateGradientRangeArray = (data: IGradient): GradientType => {
  const { colors, direction, name, positions } = data;
  const rangeColorsArray: string[] = [];

  for (const clr in colors) {
    for (const pos in positions) {
      if (clr === pos) {
        rangeColorsArray.push(`${colors[clr]} ${positions[pos]},`);
      }
    }
  }
  const createGradientString = rangeColorsArray.join(" ").slice(0, -1);

  return { name, direction, range: createGradientString };
};
```

##### types.ts

```js
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export interface IGradient {
  name: string;
  direction: string;
  colors: string[];
  positions: string[];
}

export type GradientType = { range: string } & Pick<
  IGradient,
  "name" | "direction"
>;

export interface IResult {
  data: IGradient[];
}

export interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  gradient?: GradientType;
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Answer (score 0):

> I forked into your sandbox. I corrected the types in your code so that
> they are inferred correctly by TSLint. Also you have declared interface for your props. But your code is not utilizing props anywhere.

**Below is my solution**

[image: Edit Customized_Underline_with_gradient_API_in_React-Stackoverflow]